# Loss function for differences between two tensors

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, loss-function, loss

I'm training a convolution neural network (using Tensorflow) with the method of the so called 'Knowledge Distillation (KD)' that in few words consist on training a big model (the teacher) on the task that you want to achieve and after that to train a smaller model (the student) in a way that it can simulate the results of the teacher but using less parameters and so being more quickly at test time.

The problem that I'm facing regards how to build in an effective way the loss function between the result of the student model and the teacher model on the same input (the result is a tensor with the same size either for student and teacher model).

I don't have a classification task, so I don't have a label for the input, but I have only the result from the teacher that I want to simulate.

At now the loss function is defined like this:

```
loss_value = tf.nn.l2_loss(student_prediction - teacher_prediction)
```

The 'student_prediction' and 'teacher_prediction' are calculated runtime given each input in the dataset.

With this definition I'm still not able to reach convergence with my student model.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself the answer (using MSE). That is this:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(tensor_1, tensor_2))
```